# Why is my Python package not being found?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypdf

I am using [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) to combine multiple PDF files into an output. While my code was working before, it has stopped after moving the file into a different folder on my computer. The package can no longer be found: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'`.

I started by running `pip list` to make sure the package was still there (it was). I then tried uninstalling and reinstalling it to no luck. Then, I tried moving into a virtual environment, to see if installing the package there would fix my issue. It did, and the code ran fine, however, I need this to work outside of a venv. I've removed all packages from my non-virtual environment and am left with only this:

```
Dr-Bubbles:Scripts $ pip list                            
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.0.1
PyPDF2     1.26.0
setuptools 51.3.3
wheel      0.36.2

Dr-Bubbles:Scripts $ python3 mergePdf.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mergePdf.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

For reference, here is import part of the script:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger
from rich import print
OUTPUT_DIR = "/Users/bencarpenter/OneDrive/Personal/PDFs"

def main():
     # Main function
```

Does anyone know where I went wrong? I'm open to any ideas. Many thanks!

Comment: This happened with me yesterday. I resolved it by going into interpreter settings in pycharm and adding the package from there.

Comment: Try `pip3`.....

Comment: @JonathonReinhart did that. No luck.

Comment: @vanditvasa Hmmm, don't think that would work for me here... I'll keep it in mind though. Thanks so much!

Comment: what's the first line in your script?  it maybe points to another python interpreter which different from your default env.

Comment: @bacarpenter which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Fatalerr ahhh! Thank you, it did have to do with a version error. I was using the homebrew install of pip, but the system install of python3. I've now added `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3` to my `.zshrc` file as suggested [here](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) would you like to answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. My issue was with dual installs of python3. pip is attached to my homebrew install of python but running `python3` in the cli was running the system install. To fix this, I added the line `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3` to my `.zshrc` file (as shown [here](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac)), making it so that running python3 always points to the hombrew install. Thank you to @Fatalerr for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install pip with python or did you install pip seperately? If its seperate, then you need to uninstall and reinstall python, but before that, try pip freeze>requirements.txt. You need to keep this txt file safe. After downloading, enable PATH and PIP in the installation wizard. Try pip after installing in CMD or pip3 in the terminal(if you are in MAC or Linux). After re-installing Python and pip, you need to type pip3 install -r requirements.txt, and you are all set.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, this did not fix my issue.